# Как поменять цвет ссылки при наведении на картинку?

Tags: css

```
<li class="temnyi">
    <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="svetlyi"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
</li>

.temnyi { position: relative;margin-bottom: 15px;}
.svetlyi {   position: absolute;    right: 0px;    bottom: 5px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);    padding: 4px 9px 5px 9px;   color: #fff;   width: 235px;}
.temnyi a:hover {color:#ffff99}
```

Сейчас меняется, только если на саму ссылку наводишь.
И подскажите, пожалуйста, свойство, которое увеличивает яркость картинки при наведении на нее?

Comment: Т.е. первоначально opacity: 0.7, а при наведении 1.

Comment: @rodion, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так

```
.temnyi img:hover {
    color: #000;
    }
```

Яркость измеряется от нуля до единицы, 1 - это полная яркость (белый цвет), а 0 - первоначальная яркость.

```
.temnyi img:hover {
    filter: brightness(0.2);
    -webkit-filter: brightness(0.2);
    -moz-filter: brightness(0.2);
    -o-filter: brightness(0.2);
    -ms-filter: brightness(0.2);
    }
```

Comment: браузеры, поддерживающие данный параметр http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters

Comment: @soledar10, ты прав, но другой вариант нет для css.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делают так:

Накладывают поверх картинки через псевдокласс белый фон с opacity:0.2, а потом при наведении через transition его убирают. Создается эффект контрастности и яркости. Можно наложить не белый фон, а цвет - средний от исходной картинки.

Поменять цвет ссылки:

```
img:hover a {
color:yourcolor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Про фильтры для картинок вам уже ответили. Вот решение вопроса с подсветкой ссылки при наведении на картику. У вас тайтл (.svetly) с position:absolute - вы можете без видимых изменений в отображении поменять местами в разметке его с картинкой и воспользоваться селектором "+" чтобы повлиять на следующий (в разметке) элемент.
https://jsfiddle.net/thzcr7qc/

html

```
<li class="temnyi">
    <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">php the_post_thumbnail();</a>
    <a href="<? the_permalink()?>" rel="bookmark" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" class="svetlyi">php the_title();</a>        
</li>
```

css

```
.temnyi { position: relative;margin-bottom: 15px;}
.svetlyi {   position: absolute;    right: 0px;    bottom: 5px;background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);    padding: 4px 9px 5px 9px;   color: #fff;   width: 235px;}
.temnyi a:hover, .temnyi a:first-of-type:hover + a {color:#ffff99}
```

правда теперь наверно у вас возникнет вопрос как при наведении на ссылку применять фильтр к картинке - но это уже другая история.